Matrices generate finite subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$
Show that $A:= \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}  $ and $ B:=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}  $ generate a finite subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ (set of all $2 \times2$ matrices with determinant $1$).
Is it enough to show that $AB,BA,A^{-1},B^{-1}$ all have determinant $1$ or am I wrong?
I also need to check whether this subgroup is normal. Is it correct to check if $gAg^{-1}=A,gBg^{-1}=B$ for some $g \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$?
Thank you!

You don't need to check determinant $1$ since that follows directly from multiplicativity. It is the finiteness condition that matters here. You need to show that products of $A$ and $B$ will not generate an infinite subgroup.

Thanks! Can you help me with that?

Both your suggested strategies are not what you want. The first item has nothing to do with the property you want (and is in fact automatically fulfilled if $A,B$ are both from $\mathrm{SL}_2{\mathbb{Z}}$). The second one is a bit ambiguous. If you intend to show this for each $g$, then the subgroup is central (and therefore also normal), but this is not necessary for normality. If you just want to find a specific $g$, this will show nothing (since $g=1$ always does this). I suggest that you just work straight with the definitions here.

$A^2=B^3=I_2$ so products of $A$ and $B$ will eventually terminate to the identity matrix? Does this show finiteness of the subgroup?

No, not on its own. There are groups generated by such elements (of orders $2$ and $3$ that is) that are not even torsion (for instance, the closely related $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is such a group). To finish the argument, you also need to control how $A$ and $B$ interact.

Thanks, but I don't come up with a solution ... Can you show it to me?

Am I think wrong?  Since $AB=-B$ and $-B^3=A^2=I_2=-A$, for ecah $x\in \left< A,B \right> $, if $x=A^{a_1}B^{b_1}A^{a_2}B^{b_2}\cdots A^{a_n}B^{b_n}$, $x=(-1)^{a_1+\cdots a_n}B^{b_1+\cdots b_2}$. You can calcuate $B^0, B, B^2, B^3, B^4,B^5, B^6=I_2$, so we just need calcuate $b_1+\cdots b_n (\mathrm{mod} 6) . $
